# Angular form validation using ng-model or forrn input name?

Tags: angular, angular-validation

When providing validation feedback on an input field there are two ways to check as far I can see:

```
<form name="myform" ng-submit="myform && myFunc()">
 <input name="foo" ng-model="foo" required>
 <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The following both work:

```
<div class="error" ng-show="myform.$submitted && myform.foo.$invalid">Feedback</div>

<div class="error" ng-show="myform.$submitted && !foo">Feedback</div>
```

That is to use the `ng-model` or the `fornm.input`'s name? Is one preferable over the other or considered best practice?

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with **dynamic** form inputs, the *second one seems cleaner* and *fault tolerant* when you may **add** or **remove** inputs conditionally, but the first one looks for *existing* input inside the form and you have to consider possible errors perhaps by adding another condition.

Angular is a powerful platform and this is your role to detect strong features in order to write clean and short codes without getting possible errors.